# What dlls must i reference to get access to JsonArray in .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, arrays

I am trying to use the JsonArray class in a new empty asp.net mvc4 project in visual studio 2012 RC. However, I can't seem to get access to the class.

I read in the documentation that the class is defined in the System.Runtime.Serialization.dll in the namespace System.Json. However, when I have added the dll file in my project, and open it in Object Browser, the namespace System.Json is not in there.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Have they relocated the class in the RC?

Comment: hmmm.... System.Runtime.Serialization (the .NETCore\v4.5 version) actually looks completely empty in Object Browser on my test machine... but some types are resolving to it... very odd. But hacking around, I agree: JsonArray isn't there, despite [MSDN saying it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonarray(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I also use v4.5. System.Runtime.Serialization.dll is not empty on my machine, but the namespace System.Json is not to be found. If I search for JsonArray in the Object Explorer  (.net Framework 4.5) I get no results.

Comment: Indeed; I've checked both the regular .NET and metro profiles... it is notable by its absence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need Json.Net

From [Scott Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

> We on the web team will be including JSON.NET as the default JSON
>   Serializer in Web API when it releases, so that'll be nice.

Comment: You know what, I am starting to believe this has something to do with it. The JSON.NET nuget package is installed by default in the template I use.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Json.net installed add a using statement

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

then you can use JArray in place of JsonArray   and JObject in place of JsonObject